# Bacterial Growth Formula

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, lab-techniques, growth

What are the units of $N$: the colonies of bacteria or the viable cell count?

This is in regards to the bacterial growth formula used during serial dilutions,

$$
N =N(0) e^{kt} \quad .
$$

Answer (score 3):

Either; they're identical to the units of $N(0)$.  In $N =N(0) e^{kt}$,

- $t$ has units of time (days, minutes, whatever you have chosen)
- $k$ has units of (1/time) (inverse of $t$'s units)
- $kt$ is thus *unitless*, as is $e^{kt}$
- $N$ and $N(0)$ have the same units.

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ is a number of something, like anything that is just a number, it is dimensionless and unitless, or with dimension and unit 1.

Note that in chemistry, the "amount" of a substance is not dimensionless but of dimension "amount of matter", with the *mole* as unit. It is however connected to the number (dimensionless and unitless) of elementary entities in this substance (whether they are atomes, molecules, etc.) through the Avogadro's constant ($N_A = 6,022 140 76 × 10^{23}$ mol$^{–1}$).

However, if your question is whether $N$ and $N(0)$ count the number of individual cells or the number of colonies, I think there is some confusion in your question as the number of colonies (after plating) is a proxi for quantifying the number of viable cells at the moment of plating. But you cannot apply the formula directly to the "number of colonies" since *once plated* this number will not increase exponentially but stay constant. So $N$ and $N(0)$ refer to the number of (viable) cells.